# React Native App - Name change in Xcode - no longer runs ' ***App has not been registered

Tags: xcode, react-native

I have an elaborate React Native App which has been running perfectly until we decided to make it a white label product.

The name of the project had changed - we changed styling etc and everything was complete and tested - then I noticed the 'identity and Type' section in Xcode and an editable name box - i changed the name to the new white label brand.  Xcode whirred away changing file names.

I tried to run the app in the ios simulator - it built but displayed an error:

[image]

I cleaned build folder.  Same error - removed app cache - same error.

So i changed the name back to LRMApp as seen below:
[image]

Still get the same error - refuses to run at all!
Can anyone offer some advice to fix?  I can role back to previous repo commit but would have to dissect a lot of work from a merge, so hoping there is an easy fix!

Comment: After you replace it, did you shut down the xcode and try running it again?

Comment: @hongdevelop yes, closed down, cleared cache - reset simulator cache and settings - same error..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are things to make sure that the **changed name** is returned to its **original name.**

1. You have to make sure that you changed the name of the project. Name
   of the top-level folder in the project
2. Did you change the **identity and type** name?
3. Check out the name of the `Scheme`.
4. Check the internal folder name of the project.
5. Please check the name under '**identity and type**' by selecting a
   subfolder for your project.
6. Check the name of the '`Info.plist`' file in the Packaging menu.
7. Check out the name of the `'Product Bundle Identifier'` in the
   Packaging menu.

Comment: Brilliant thanks - tried all above and the name was missing in Plist - still didnt run so did a find and replace for the previous name cross project - this seems to have done the trick...  thanks for your help..